# Interfacing Arduino with MATLAB for image processing 

Tags: c, matlab, arduino

How can I connect an Arduino board and MATLAB for image processing?
I am making an autonomous robot which require image processing in MATLAB.

Comment: Posting [two questions with the same title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003512/matlab-image-processing) in rapid succession can easily confuse people. It would be better to differentiate your questions clearly with different titles.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the MATLAB-to-Arduino package at the offical MATLAB site, "[MATLAB Interface to Arduino](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/arduino-software/arduino-matlab.html)".

Answer (score 1):

If you have serial communication on the Arduino, Matlab has built in tools for talking with the chip over USB or RS232. It is fairly simple to setup, but if your images are high in resolution you may not get the necessary speed from standard RS232.

something along the lines of:

```
s=serial('COM1','baudrate',115200)
```

Then you can read and write to the Arduino through Matlab functions and scripts

Answer (score 1):

You can get connected to the MATLAB interface by simply using the `serial` and `fopen` commands on MATLAB

eg:

```
s=serial('COM2','Baudrate',9600,'Databits',8);

fopen(s);

count=0;

while count<50

    a=fscanf(s);

    count=count+1;

end

fclose(s);
```

whereas on Arduino, use `Serial.print()` function.

Simple data can be sent using this. I never tried camera by using this technique. But by using a camera shield mounted on Ardunino, taking snapshots and later sending the data through Arduino to MATLAB as a matrix might work. Just an idea, might be possible.

Edit1:
I was looked up more into this, and found some potential hardwares for the same:
 1. ArduCam Shield for Arduino
 2. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11418

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it would work definitely.

MATLAB can be handy if you try following steps:

1. Try the basic LED program which will let you know if you've successfully connected with the Arduino or not. Once achieved successfully.
2. Now create ARDUINO program and dump the program in the card so as how it has to perform.
3. Then, use the fopen and fwrite commands in MATLAB to run the program.

**FREE TIP:** always use fclose command as soon as you're done with the communication with ARDUINO else it would remain busy and then would require you to configure it on some other port.

You can find relevant code samples in the help based on your MATLAB version.